# Multiply two fields if an ID is found in a separate table

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, sql, automationstudio

Trying to create a Data Extension where we calculate the total spend in a category, if the category exists in a list of promotional categories. The point is that we want to provide an offer when a minimum spend is achieved.

I can't seem to figure this out and have been digging for some time.  Below is the part that is tripping me up.  **CategoryID** is in the table being evaludated and there are potential matches in **Offers**.  I tried to `CAST` the results, but not luck.  I only want to find the total spend on the product if the product is in the right category.

The **ExtPrice** field is **Decimal(10,2)** and the **Quantity** field is a **Number**

`CASE when CategoryID in (Select ID from Offers) Then (CAST(ExtPrice as Decimal(10,2)) * CAST(Quantity as Decimal(10,2))) end as Product1_TotalSpend`

If someone can point me in the right direction, it would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select
i.orderNum
, sum(
    case when o.offerID is not null then i.extprice else 0 end
) promoSpend
, sum (
    case when o.offerID is null then i.extprice else 0 end
) nonPromoSpend
from orderItems i
left join Offers o on o.offerid = i.categoryID
group by
i.ordernum
```

Here's a link to the test: https://rextester.com/VPCU67650

Comment: Thank you.  This definitely got me to my answer.  What I didn't mention is that I had to multiply the quantity by the price to get to a total spend, but what you provided got me 90% of the way there.  I owe you a beverage.